# How can I make my server be able to be connected through a bridged connection

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote

I want to connect to my server but I'm in anthor branch with is bridged to the router of the main branch, I want to connect to it through rdp but its only possible when being in the same branch our main server is able to do it but I don't know how

Specs: HPE DL380 G7
Windows server 2008 x86

If there's anything needed please let me know and I will provide it at my best

Comment: Which of the two routers do you control ?

Comment: The main router